# parse JSON coming from a REST service in a React Native app

Tags: json, react-native

I need help to parse the following JSON coming from a REST service.

I want to read into an array and further each item I have to display on a mobile screen.

```
[ 
    { 
      "Login": 
        { 
            "Status": "Success", 
            "nm_vw": { 
                      "EMPLID": "88888",
                      "NAME": "sample test"
                     } 
        } 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access data like:

```
let data=[ 
    { 
      "Login": 
        { 
            "Status": "Success", 
            "nm_vw": { 
                      "EMPLID": "88888",
                      "NAME": "sample test"
                     } 
        } 
    }
];
```

to access status use:

```
console.log(data[0]['Login']['Status']);
```

to read emplid:

```
console.log(data[0]['Login']['nm_vw']['EMPLID']);
```